# Evaluate integral: $ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\log|z-x|}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, potential-theory

Show that
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\log|z-x|}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \log{\frac{|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}|}{2}},\quad z \in \mathbb{C}
$$

How can I apply the Joukowski conformal map to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: A trivial question: what is the motivation behind this integral? Are you expecting a contour integral or something to solve this? It does not seem to related to conformal mapping.