# Question about $\int_{-1}^{1} \log |z-x| dx, z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: integration, potential-theory

I am wondering if this integral can be evaluated using the "usual" integration techniques. I have written $| z - x | = \sqrt{(\operatorname{Re}({z}) - x)^2 + \operatorname{Im}(z)^2}$ but it doesn't seem to do much good..

According to the question [Evaluate integral: $ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\log|z-x|}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117236/evaluate-integral-int-11-frac-logz-x-pi-sqrt1-x2dx), it may require knowledge of conformal mappings, is this true?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: $|z-x| = \sqrt{(\text{Re}(z)-x)^2 + \text{Im}(z)^2}$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you. I have corrected the question.

Comment: You still left out the square on the $\text{Im}(z)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No special knowledge required.  Integrate by parts.

EDIT:
If you want it in terms of $\log(z-1)$ and $\log(z+1)$, don't use real and imaginary parts.  Instead,
write $$\log |z - x| = \log \sqrt{(z - x)(\bar{z} - x)} = \dfrac{1}{2} \log (z-x) + \dfrac{1}{2} \log(\bar{z} - x)$$
For this to be valid you have to be a bit careful about which branch of the logarithm of complex numbers you use: you want the one with imaginary part in $(-\pi, \pi]$, and avoid having $z - x$ on the negative real axis.  Since $x$ will go from $-1$ to $1$ in your integral, you don't want $z$ in $(-\infty, 1]$.

Then
$$\eqalign{&\left. \int_{-1}^1 \log(z-x) \ dx =  (x-z) \log(z-x) + z - x \right|_{x=-1}^1 \cr&= (1-z) \log(z-1) + (1+z) \log(z+1) - 2}$$

The integral of $\log(\bar{z} - x)$ is the complex conjugate of this, so
you get $\text{Re} ( (1-z) \log(z-1) + (1+z) \log(z+1)) - 2$.

Comment: Hello. I am having trouble with the integral. I am supposed to find $-2 + \operatorname{Re}((z + 1)\log(z + 1) - (z - 1)\log(z - 1))$, but I'm not sure how I can find that..