# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^1\log|s-x|dx$ for complex $s$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Find $$\int_{-1}^1\log|s-x|\,\mathrm{d}x$$ that arises in deriving the Runge region, which seems to be (from *Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice*)
$$-2+\mathrm{Re }[(s+1)\log(s+1)-(s-1)\log(s-1)].\tag{1}$$
I attempted to write $s=a+bi$ then write $\log|s-x|=\log\sqrt{(a-x)^2+b^2}=\frac12\log((a-x)^2+b^2)$, which involves $\arctan({a\pm1\over b})$ that can be viewed as $\arg(s\pm1)$, and can be finally simplified to (1). But is there any more elegant way to find (1)?

Comment: Could you give a reference for what you call a "Runge region" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Sure, it is the soccer-like region where f should be analytic, so that interpolations through equispaced points will converge to f as the number of points tends to infinity. Analyticity in this region can avoid Runge phenomenon, which was discovered by Runge. See more details in the book *Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice: Extended Edition*, Chapter 13.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/780568/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you!